# Issue mapping a list of values into a class Scala

Tags: scala

I have two classes:

```
class Person(name: String)
class Persons(people: List[Persons]
```

I want to create a companion object that accepts a list of Strings, makes each one into a person, and creates a Persons object.

```
object Persons {
    def apply(people: List[String]) = new Persons(people.map(_ => new Person(_)))
}
```

However, this doesn't work. It turns out that

```
people.map(_ => new Person(_))
```

Is creating a function mapping

```
List[(String) => Person]
```

I managed to get the result I'm after using a for comprehension, but I'm unclear as to what's going on using map.

```
def apply(ppl: List[String]): Persons = {
    new Persons(for {
    p <- ppl
    person = new Person(p)
} yield person)
```

}

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this using map and maybe explain what's going in my incorrect attempt?

Comment: `.map` takes a function of arity 1 `A => B`, whereas `_ => new Person(_)` with 2 `_` defines a function of arity 2: either `x => new Person(x)` or `new Person(_)` (`_` is only used on the left of `=>` to ignore parameters, not to apply without naming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already figured out, `map(_ => new Person(_)` would create a list of functions:

```
val names = List("Dave", "Jenn", "Mike")
names.map(_ => new Person(_))
// res1: List[String => Person] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
```

The following `map` is what you're seeking:

```
names.map(new Person(_))
// res2: List[Person] = List(Person@16cf05ef, Person@34d53f54, Person@5417d740)
```

Putting them together:

```
class Person(name: String)
class Persons(people: List[Person])
object Persons {
    def apply(people: List[String]) = new Persons(people.map(new Person(_)))
}

val people = List(new Person("Dave"), new Person("Jenn"), new Person("Mike"))
val groupOfPeople1 = new Persons(people)

val names = List("Dave", "Jenn", "Mike")
val groupOfPeople2 = Persons(names)
```

Comment: If you use a case class like I did below you don't even need the new you can shorten it with `people.map(People)` I wrote a bit more below

Answer (score 2):

does this do what you are looking for?

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SphW7AG7T7WgIGEXYN4U3w

```
case class Person(name: String)
class Persons(people: List[Person]) {
  def getPeople: List[Person] = people
}

object Persons {
  def apply(p: String*): Persons = new Persons(p.map(Person).toList)
  def apply(p: List[String]): Persons = new Persons(p.map(Person))
}

val p = Persons("Steve", "Dave", "Bob")
val p2 = Persons(List("Steve", "Bob", "Dave"))

p.getPeople.foreach { person => 
    println(person.name)
}

p2.getPeople.foreach { person => 
    println(person.name)
}
```

I like to use case classes because they make construction very easy like above. I also only used a list because it was what you used so I assume you wanted a list. I'm happy to answer any other questions you might have.